# Split Column Characters to rows Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have searched everywhere for this function and I am almost giving up on it. I have an Oracle table that Looks like this:

```
name      Number_of_Leaves    status
cheque1        5              PPURI
cheque4        10             UUSPDRIPPP
```

The Status Column shows the Status of each cheque leaf either Passes,Stopped,Destroyed,Issued and so on.
I need to represent the information in a view like this: for every cheque Status, I should Have a Single row:

```
name      Number_of_Leaves    status
    cheque1        5              P
    cheque1        5              P
    cheque1        5              U
    cheque1        5              R
    cheque1        5              I
    cheque4        10             U
    cheque4        10             U
    cheque4        10             S
    cheque4        10             P
    cheque4        10             D
    ...............................
```

Is this Achievable in any way Possible???

Comment: Please give an example..

Comment: What Kind of example? I already gave example above??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this function by yourself ;) For example, using TABLE operator and predefined split function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_char IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1)

/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TMP_SPLIT(p_val VARCHAR2)
RETURN t_char IS
v_res t_char;
BEGIN
v_res := t_char(SUBSTR(p_val,1,1));
v_res.extend(LENGTH(p_val)-1);
FOR i IN 2..LENGTH(p_val) LOOP
    v_res(i) := SUBSTR(p_val,i,1);
END LOOP;
RETURN v_res;
END;

/

WITH dat AS (SELECT 'cheque1' name,
                    5 Number_of_Leaves,
                    'PPURI' status FROM DUAL
             UNION 
             SELECT 'cheque4' name,
                    10 Number_of_Leaves,
                    'UUSPDRIPPP' status FROM DUAL)
SELECT dat.name, dat.number_of_leaves, spl.*
FROM dat 
     LEFT JOIN TABLE(TMP_SPLIT(dat.status)) spl ON 1=1

/
```

---

An example of calling function for existing table:

```
SELECT table1.name, table1.number_of_leaves, spl.*
FROM table1
     LEFT JOIN TABLE(TMP_SPLIT(table1.status)) spl ON 1=1
```

Comment: The Status will change this is Just an example. If I have 50 leaves I will have 50 Statuses.

Comment: @Stanley So? The function will work the same, i don't get what's the problem.

Comment: So i will have to Manually pass the values for a thousand records like this?? See My concern is that this is not Dynamic as the values`UUSPDRIPPP` and `PPURI` are hard-coded.

Comment: @Stanley Of course, not :) This was just an example, so i don't had to create a table in my test schema. You can apply it to existing table - check the updated answer.

Comment: Oh I got it now, I do not need the Part starting `WITH dat as...` for an existing table right???

Comment: @Stanley Sure, this way i just emulated `SELECT * FROM table1`, which I don't have in my schema :)

Comment: Great , I think This is what I will go with. Accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible my friend:

```
with tab1(rn,name,status,Number_of_Leaves,tes) as 
(select 1 rn,name,status,Number_of_Leaves,substr(status,1,1) tes from table1
union all 
select rn + 1 rn,name,status,Number_of_Leaves,substr(status,rn + 1,1) tes from tab1
where rn < Number_of_Leaves),
tab2 as (select status,rn,name,Number_of_Leaves,Tes from 
tab1 order by status,rn)
select name,Number_of_Leaves,Tes status from tab2;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f5978/19)

Comment: Yours seem to be what I am looking for Judging from the fiddle but I am really trying to understand the sql. Am green :)

Comment: Am gettting `ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing` am on Oracle 11g